# Is there any reference for the optimal bound $3|M|-1$ in Simon factorization forest theorem?

Tags: reference-request, automata, semigroups, monoid

Let $S$ be a finite semigroup. A *factorization tree* of a product $w_1\cdots w_n$ in $S$ is a finite ordered tree labeled by elements of $S$, such that each leaf is labeled by the $w_i$ in their order in the product, and such that each internal node is labeled by the product of their leaves (in their order). A factorization tree is *Ramseyan* if each internal node of arity $3$ or more has all its children labeled by the same idempotent.

**Theorem.** (Simon) Each product in a finite semigroup $S$ has a Ramseyan factorization tree of height at most $9|S|$.

The bound was later improved to at least $3|S|$. I found in the two papers [1] and [2] the mention that this bound can be improved to $3|S|-1$. Here is a quote from [2]:

> The improved bound $3 |S| − 1$ can be obtained from the current proof by some additional rotation technique as in the proof of Lemma 2. We postpone this proof to a forthcoming journal version of this article.

However, I found no such journal version and was unable to reconstruct the proof for the bound $3|S|-1$. We can make a recurrence from the lowest Green $\mathcal{J}$-classes to the highest instead of the other way around but I still obtained the bound $3|S|$ instead of $3|S|-1$.

Can someone give a proof of this result or a reference?

[1] [*Factorization forests for infinite words and applications to countable scattered linear orderings*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397509007555) (Colcombet, 2010)
[2] [*The Height of Factorization Forests*](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.150.3842) (Kufleitner, 2008)

Answer (score 1):

The published version of [2] is

M. Kufleitner, The height of factorization forests. In E. Ochmanski and J. Tyszkiewicz, editors, *Proc. 33rd Symp., Mathematical Foundations of Computer Science 2008*, volume 5162 of *Lecture Notes in Comput. Sci.*, pages 443–454. Springer, 2008.

It contains a detailed proof of the result you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I found in this article the same mention "We postpone this proof to a forthcoming journal version of this article."... So I don't really understand. I also found in the article by Colcombet *Green's Relations and their Use in Automata Theory* a proof but it seems to be incomplete to me: the rotation technique necessary for the bound $3|S|$ is apparently left implicit and it is said that it provides the bound $3|S|-1$.

Comment: But I found an other article by Colcombet with a different proof ("[The factorisation Forest Theorem](https://www.irif.fr/~colcombe/Publications/handbook-fft-colcombet_non-final.pdf)").

Comment: I should have mentioned this reference immediately! I strongly recommend this article.